# Snowflake - Can a user have both basic authentication and key pair authentication?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We have a service account, which is used for development purposes. Can we have this user authenticated with key pair (2048-bit RSA key pair) and basic authentication (i.e. username and password) both ?

If so how should we create that user ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. Just set the password field and the RSA_PUBLIC_KEY field